# imagemagick white-threshold and monochrome options dont work together

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a PDF to a TIFF using Imagemagick.  I would like there to be no halftoning or dots for gray in my resulting tiff.  Therefore, I am specifying a white-threshold in my convert command.

I would also like the document to be monochrome, so I specified the monochrome option as well.

If I specify both monochrome and white-threshold (I set the threshold to 0% for testing purposes), all of my gray areas on the document are halftoned and have dots in them, but the conversion process is very fast.  Example:

```
convert -density 150 -monochrome -white-threshold 60% in.pdf out.tiff
```

If I only specify white-threshold and drop monochrome, the halftoning is dropped (I only get white where the gray areas area) but the process takes 8 times as long.

```
convert -density 150 white-threshold 60% in.pdf out.tiff
```

I'm using Version: ImageMagick 6.7.0-10  on Ubuntu 12.10 x64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the excellent [Examples of ImageMagick Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/), especially:

- [Threshold Dithering Methods](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#threshold)
- [Two Color Quantization](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#two_color)

The easiest way to achieve the desired result is:

```
convert -density 150 -threshold 60% in.pdf out.tiff
```